ItemSource для Listbox переопределяет itemsource для вложенного Combobox
Мой combobox использует itemsource который указан для listbox, как я могу переписать код, чтобы он обращался к другим данным из ViewModel ?
<Grid>
<ScrollViewer>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Orders}" x:Name="LboxProducts" Width="650" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ListBoxItem BorderBrush="Black" Background="White" Width="600">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <TextBlock Text="" x:Name="TxtProductPath" Style="{StaticResource mainTxtb}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding NameOrder}" x:Name="TxtTitle" Style="{StaticResource mainTxtb}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" x:Name="TxtDescription" Style="{StaticResource mainTxtb}"/>
                            <ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding OrderStatusId, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedValuePath="OrderStatusId" DisplayMemberPath="StatusName" ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={}}" x:Name="Combobox1" Style="{StaticResource mainCmbx}" SelectionChanged="Combobox1_SelectionChanged"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ListBoxItem>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
<StackPanel>
    <Button Command="{Binding Save}" x:Name="BtnSave" Content="Сохранить" Style="{StaticResource mainBtn}"/>
</StackPanel>

Вот код ViewModel, OrderStatuses таблица связанная с Orders по ключу OrderStatusId
так же хотелось бы чтобы Кнопка Save так же была в каждом ListBoxItem
internal class PageOrdersViewModel 
{
private bool needToCheck = true;
private List<Order> orders = ConnectToDb.db.Orders.ToList();
public List<Order> Orders
    {
        get => orders;
        set => orders = value;
    }

private void ValidateProperty<T>(T value, string propertyName)
{
    if (needToCheck)
    {
        Validator.ValidateProperty(value, new ValidationContext(this, null, null)
        {
            MemberName = propertyName
        });

    }
}

public IEnumerable<OrderStatus> OrderStatuses  => ConnectToDb.db.OrderStatuses.ToList();

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}

public RelayCommand save;
public RelayCommand Save
{
    get
    {
        return save ?? (new RelayCommand(obj =>
        {
            try
            {
                
                if (needToCheck != null)
                {
                    
                    ConnectToDb.db.SaveChanges();
                    SupplyMethods.SetMessageToStatusBar("Успешно изменено");
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                SupplyMethods.SetMessageToStatusBar($"Ошибка добавления. {ex.Message}");
            }
        }));
    }
}
}


Найдите предка через FindAncestor и через его DataContext привяжитесь к нужному свойству (пример, TvNodes меняйте на DataContext.Save).

@EvgeniyZ а могу ли я обратится к классу ViewModel напрямую через RelativeSource или какой мне нужно выбрать AncestorType чтобы он обратился к классу т.к. я полагаю тип Window не подходит

Повторю - ищите предка, который в визуальном дереве на уровень выше находится, это может быть что угодно, от ListBox до самого окна. Найти его вы можете хоть по имени, хоть через FindAncestor. Найдя предка, берите его DataContext - это и будет ваша VM. Ну а уже из этого свойства берите любое другое свойство, которое находится в VM.

@EvgeniyZ Большое спасибо, использовал AncestorType=Page и все заработало как нужно!

Так же вы можете использовать vm как ресурс для текущего контекста. Это не является практикой для mvvm, в комментариях более подробное обсуждение. И как в примере vm это ресурс view, то при каждом создание окна будет создана новая vm.
<Window x:Class="Users"
        ------------------
        DataContext="{DynamicResource vm}">
    <Window.Resources>
        <vm:PageOrdersViewModel x:Key="vm"/>
    </Window.Resources>

 <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Orders}" x:Name="LboxProducts" Width="650" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ListBoxItem BorderBrush="Black" Background="White" Width="600">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <TextBlock Text="" x:Name="TxtProductPath" Style="{StaticResource mainTxtb}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding NameOrder}" x:Name="TxtTitle" Style="{StaticResource mainTxtb}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" x:Name="TxtDescription" Style="{StaticResource mainTxtb}"/>
                            <ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding OrderStatusId, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedValuePath="OrderStatusId" DisplayMemberPath="StatusName"  ItemsSource="{Binding  OrderStatuses , Source={StaticResource vm}}" x:Name="Combobox1" Style="{StaticResource mainCmbx}" SelectionChanged="Combobox1_SelectionChanged"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ListBoxItem>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>

Подобное используется по типу локатора.
Так же вам ранее описали как при помощи восходящих привязок обратиться к DataContext.
так же хотелось бы чтобы Кнопка Save так же была в каждом ListBoxItem
Вы можете сделать что то подобное этому.
<ListBoxItem BorderBrush="Black" Background="White" Width="600">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <TextBlock Text="" x:Name="TxtProductPath" Style="{StaticResource mainTxtb}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding NameOrder}" x:Name="TxtTitle" Style="{StaticResource mainTxtb}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" x:Name="TxtDescription" Style="{StaticResource mainTxtb}"/>
                            <ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding OrderStatusId, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedValuePath="OrderStatusId" DisplayMemberPath="StatusName"  ItemsSource="{Binding  OrderStatuses , Source={StaticResource vm}}" x:Name="Combobox1" Style="{StaticResource mainCmbx}" SelectionChanged="Combobox1_SelectionChanged"/>
<Button Command="{Binding Save, Source={StaticResource vm}}" x:Name="BtnSave" Content="Сохранить" Style="{StaticResource mainBtn}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ListBoxItem>

Но при вызове команды SelectedItem будет пустой если кликнуть сразу на кнопку без выбора Item, и может возникнуть ситуация к примеру если у вас была бы не кнопка сохранить, а кнопка удалить. В этом случае выбор Item был бы лишним действием, а без этого действия команда работала бы криво.
Тогда решения могут быть следующими
Передать в команду параметр с текущим Item
<Button Command="{Binding Save, Source={StaticResource vm}}" CommandParametr="{Binding}" x:Name="BtnSave" Content="Сохранить" Style="{StaticResource mainBtn}"/>

public RelayCommand Save
{
    get
    {
        return save ?? (new RelayCommand(obj =>
        {
            try
            {
                var temp = obj as Order;
                 if(temp != null)
{
//Какая то обработка.
}
                if (needToCheck != null)
                {
                    
                    ConnectToDb.db.SaveChanges();
                    SupplyMethods.SetMessageToStatusBar("Успешно изменено");
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                SupplyMethods.SetMessageToStatusBar($"Ошибка добавления. {ex.Message}");
            }
        }));
    }
}

Или же вы можете использовать PreviewGotKeyboardFocus чтобы при фокусе на кнопку SelectedItem(у) были присвоены данные. Я бы использовал этот вариант так как он более рационален.
Вот готовые примеры:

Использование Attached Property
Использование тригера для PreviewGotKeyboardFocus


Плохое решение, и яб даже сказал, нарушающее VM. Добавив в XAML ресурсы какой либо класс, за вас будет автоматически создан новый объект данного типа, а не конкретная VM. Также, View слой вдруг начинает знать про VM, и еще жуже, View начинает отвечать за VM, за ее срок жизни, и так далее, что думаю понимаете, является грубым нарушением VM. О том, почему не стоит в XAML создавать VM написано тут.

@EvgeniyZ это один из вариантов как использовать vm.  Вы написали ответ об восходящей привязке. И дополнили мой ответ об использование локатора. Подобную реализацию более подробно можно тут изучить https://www.dir.by/developer/wpf/locator/new_application/
Я считаю что лучше использовать что то осознанно, а не потому что на другое знаний нет.
В целом я не согласен с вами потому как здесь так и вопросе нет речи о паттерне. А вопрос о том как можно что либо сделать. Автор вопроса получил два ответа. Когда речь зайдет о правильности, то он уже будет знать что можно использовать, а что нет.

У вопроса стоит метка MVVM, что обозначает его соблюдения. В любом случае, это не отменяет того факта, что вы создаете при каждом рендере страницы постоянно новую VM, которой будет не так просто управлять в других классах, а это, ну уж извините, даже если мы не говорим о MVVM, очень плохо.

@EvgeniyZ  такое использование не редкое в wpf, но для mvvm это не правильно. И для более хороших реализаций это не несет хорошего характера из за ограниченного срока жизни view.  Изучил то что по ссылке. В DataTemplate было бы изящнее указывать.  Вместо явно задания DataContext. Тут он и связывает view с vm.  Это равно тому что для DataContext в конструктор была бы передана vm.
Поэтому суждение Согласно паттерну MVVM, View не должно руководить VM, и знать о нём должно как можно меньше. То есть код, обслуживающий UI, не должен создавать себе VM сам. Противоречит само себе.

Это равно - нет, не равно. Передав в DataTemplate тип, WPF делаете typeof(тип), он не создает его, он просто сверяет входящий тип, не более. А вот конструктор, это тесная связь View и VM, а если еще и DataContext будет задан в XAML, то там и вовсе постоянно будет new VM() вызываться...

@EvgeniyZ тогда как объясните подобную практику?
  {       
      public ActionProductUC? ActionProductUC { get => Get<ActionProductUC?>(); set { Set(value); } }```
Вызов uc
```if ("ActionProductUC_Edit".Equals(e.Parameter))
    {
        app.locator.ChildContext = new ActionProductVM(true);
    }```
```<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ActionProductVM}">
    <uc:ActionProductUC/>
</DataTemplate>```
DataContext для этого uc ни разу не где не задается в коде. NavigatorLocator используется в качестве локатора.

public object? ChildContext { get => Get<object>(); set => Set(value); }

Мне сложно по обрывку судить код. Если этот Вызов uc в VM слое и VM ничего не знает про V, то почему бы и нет, через "прослойку" управляется UI. Такое даже проще сделать на интерфейсах, где VM будет реализовать интерфейс, а V иметь в себе свойство данного интерфейса, из которого и будет брать данные. Абстракция и все дела, V и VM не связаны друг с другом, все ОК. А вот если Вызов uc находится в UI (View), то тогда это уже нарушение MVVM. А так, не забывайте, MVVM это набор рекомендаций, каждый устанавливает свои рамки дозволенного, но в вопросе у вас сейчас нарушение MVVM и это факт)

@EvgeniyZ про mvvm не хочу спорить ибо достаточно на эту тему наобщался уже) И паттерн этот понимаю. И  но в вопросе у вас сейчас нарушение MVVM и это факт) если речь о вопросе то нарушение у автора в команде Save. А если речь о моем ответе, то я ранее писал: для mvvm это не правильно. И для более хороших реализаций это не несет хорошего характера это один из вариантов как использовать vm  Так что в комментариях я подчеркнул не правильность. И подчеркнул почему это оставил как есть.

В ответе, да. Под вечер уже голова не соображает... Такое надо писать в ответе, что это не MVVM решение, тогда ок, претензий нет, но сейчас вы просто дали плохое решение человеку, который следует MVVM. Также надо указывать то, что в вашем решение будет постоянно новая VM создаваться, что также привнесет свои трудности (как например человеку взять из нее данные, например, из другой VM? И тут пойдут костыли по типу var vm = (VM)page.DataContext и тому подобное) )

@EvgeniyZ с другой стороны это могло быть полноценным локатором, который является прослойкой и DataContext мог бы зависеть от этого локатора. А в реализации локатора vm была бы абстрактной или как IVm = new Vm()l;  И все вызовы были бы в OnStartup.   Тогда это не нарушало бы паттерн.  Но это тема уже для нового вопроса конечно.
Я исправил ответ, добавив ваши замечания туда)
